# NPM Install error / Proyecto Pacman Game / Weibenfalk

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando ejecutar correctamente el juego completo de Pacman con JS, siguiendo este tutorial en Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBtzzVwrTeE&list=WL&index=9&t=290s , dentro de este tutorial exigen que se ejecute por terminal el comando 'npm install' y luego de que se haya instalado todo bajo ese comando, se ejecute el siguiente comando 'npm start', hago los pasos correspondientes al tutorial pero me da errores extraños. No entiendo bien que pasa y por eso mismo necesito ayuda por favor.

** SE QUE TIENE QUE VER ALGO CON QUE HAY COSAS OBSOLETAS, PERO QUIERO VER OPINIONES DE SOLUCION **

LOS ERRORES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

INTENTE INSTALAR LOS ERRORES QUE SALIAN AHI, PERO NADA DIO RESULTADO ! AYUDA !

Comment: Es preferible subir el código antes que una imagen, no puedo ver bien los errores porque las fotos están en baja resolución.

Comment: No es codigo, es un error en la terminal, al ejecutar el npm install. 

Lo explique en la descripcion

Comment: *quiero ver opiniones de solución*, por lo cual tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y terminaría cerrada, a menos que la edites, agregando el contenido del archivo `package.json` (en formato texto y no en imagen), la versión de Node sobre la cual estás trabajando, los primeros errores que te arroja la consola (en texto y no en imagen). Si el tutorial es muy antiguo deberías considerar buscar uno más actualizado. Por último, recuerda que las imágenes casi no aportan nada en las preguntas, a excepción de que desees mostrar un *layout* muy específico. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.